# Direct File upload to Google Cloud cdn Storage in Angular without uploading file to app server

Tags: angularjs, google-app-engine, file-upload, google-api, google-cloud-storage

I'm using cloud storage(bucket) as a cdn server for my application. I do not store the user upload files on my app server instead they are saved to Google cloud. Current implementation is as follows: user upload file from website(HTML page) to API server and then API server save this file to Google cloud storage(CDN/bucket), which is a dual process.

But now I want to direct upload file from angular HTML page i.e. from website to the Google cloud storage. I know we can upload file from API server(python or java or many other) to cloud storage but I don't want to do that. The reason behind is that I want to eliminate dual process time means first uploading file to our server and then server will send that file to google cloud. If the file size is small above we can consider the above work flow but what if I'm uploading large size files to server.

Is this possible to create some Authentication Headers values on server side and client(HTML/website) will use it for direct uploading file to Google Cloud Storage(bucket)? And after response from google cloud api the client will call the API server to save the respective changes.

I did lots of R&D's on it but did find any useful solution.
I also checked the below link but no luck.

> [Upload file to Google Cloud Storage using AngularJS multipart form data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27954229/upload-file-to-google-cloud-storage-using-angularjs-multipart-form-data)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31452720/direct-user-upload-to-gcs-with-given-name-and-parameters

Answer (score 1):

Create a signed urls to upload a file directly to gcs without authentication.
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control#Signed-URLs

Comment: The @google-cloud/storage module does not work in Angular and the code sample at that link use that module.